# Create table with column #'s and column names from a data frame with many columns

Tags: r

Just wondering how to get a simple table created by retrieving the column #'s and column names from a data frame with many columns?

Thanks

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking for

Comment: It sounds like you want to know which column name goes with which column number.  Is that right?

Comment: That is exactly right, Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the column names of a data.frame (call it `df`) using `colnames(df)` then convert that into a data.frame.

```
Cols <- data.frame("Name" = colnames(df), "Number" = 1:length(colnames(df)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code JeremyS

Answer (score 0):

It's technically not a table, but to determine the corresponding column number for a column name, this works.

```
## set up fake data 
> d <- data.frame(w = rnorm(5), x = rnorm(5), y = rf(5, 1, 1), z = rexp(5))

## solve the problem
> col <- seq(length = ncol(d))
> names(col) <- colnames(d)
> col
w x y z 
1 2 3 4
```